# Item Updated through different forms runs Item Updated event receiver

Tags: 2007, development, list, event-handlers

Simple but mind blowing question it is.

Basically I am updating a specific list items through two different ways, one is using ASP.NET web forms and one is using default list forms provided by SharePoint 2007, now I don't want "Item Updated" event to run my custom code when Item is updated through ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `EventFiringEnabled` property, you should get the event firing active/deactived.

Comment: this would work if you within the eventreciver, what if your not within the eventreciver and you dont want to call it. I presume you would need SPItemEventProperties to use that method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the event reciver by calling it and setting it to disabled. do your stuff and reenable the eventreciver:

someone has done most of the work for you :)

```
public static void RunWithEventFiringDisabled(Action action)

{

    Type typeInfo = typeof(SPEventReceiverBase);

    MethodInfo disable = typeInfo.GetMethod(“DisableEventFiring”, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    MethodInfo enable = typeInfo.GetMethod(“EnableEventFiring”, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    SPEventReceiverBase receiver = new SPEventReceiverBase();

   try
   {
        //disable it
        disable.Invoke(receiver, null);
        //do what you want to do to the list in this method 
        action();

   }
   finally
   {
        //now updating is all done you can reenable it
        enable.Invoke(receiver, null);
   }

}
```

code was taken from here:

www. sharepointboost .com/blog/how-to-update-an-item-or-a-folder-without-triggering-item-event-receiver/

For you or anyone you could split it into to methods where you can call the enable and disable individually

for disabling:

```
public static void RunWithEventFiringDisabled(Action action)
{

    Type typeInfo = typeof(SPEventReceiverBase);

     MethodInfo enable = typeInfo.GetMethod(“EnableEventFiring”, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    SPEventReceiverBase receiver = new SPEventReceiverBase();

   try
   {
        //disable it
        enable.Invoke(receiver, null);
        //do what you want to do to the list in this method 
        action();

   }
   cathc(exception a)
   {

   }
}
```

and for enabling:

```
public static void RunWithEventFiringEnabled(Action action)
{

    Type typeInfo = typeof(SPEventReceiverBase);

    MethodInfo disable = typeInfo.GetMethod(“DisableEventFiring”, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    SPEventReceiverBase receiver = new SPEventReceiverBase();

   try
   {
        //disable it
        disable.Invoke(receiver, null);
        //do what you want to do to the list in this method 
        action();

   }
   cathc(exception a)
   {

   }
}
```

call those two where required :)

**EDIT**

You could also try this as its just as good :) call this method where required instead of normal updating

```
public static void Update(this SPListItem item, bool doNotFireEvents)
{
    SPItemEventReceiverHandling rh = new SPItemEventReceiverHandling();
    if (doNotFireEvents)
    {
        try
        {
            rh.DisableEventFiring();
            item.Update();
        }
        finally
        {
            rh.EnableEventFiring();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        item.Update();
    }
}
```

http://sharepointlookup.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/updating-splistitem-without-triggering.html#!/2010/12/updating-splistitem-without-triggering.html